# How to test whether a GDI+ GraphicsPath intersects with a Rectangle on Mono?

Tags: mono, gdi+

I am trying to make a Windows.Forms code base (i.e. it uses GDI+ to draw) work on Mono.
[Mono's GDI+ support](http://www.mono-project.com/Libgdiplus) only leaves a few issues to resolve.

One of them: I need to test whether a given fragment of the drawing intersects with a given `Rectangle`.
The existing code looks like this:

```
[...]
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
[...]  // draw something to the GraphicsPath
Pen penToUse = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);  // 1 would probably do as well
gp.Widen(penToUse); //TODO: find a better way
Region reg = new Region(gp);
return reg.IsVisible(rect);
```

[Mono doesn't support `Widen`](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=320856), and when I omit it, the path has no area, causing `IsVisible` to always fail.

How can I fix this in a way Mono will support?

Comment: why not use a simple line/rectangel intersection detection function instead ?

Comment: @zinking: That works if the `GraphicsPath` always contains shapes built out of are straight lines. It does at present (which is my workaround) but I may want fancier shapes in the future.